# Get At Most One Notification a Day From Confluence

Tags: notifications, confluence

We work with Jira/Confluence. At the moment we get about 100 notifications a day. That is not working for us. It seems to be an old problem: [Notifications are sent ad-nausium, rather than queued](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-7842).
In February 2007 a workaround was posted, but sadly that link is dead.

I am told by my colleagues that it is not possible to get only one message a day: you either get every notification immediately, or none at all. As much as I dislike the flood of notifications, no notification at all is even worse in my opinion.

Is there a workaround, or do we have to accept one of the evils?

Comment: Why not work from the other end of the problem and simply have your mail client filter all of your jira notifications to a separate folder that you check once a day. Optionally your mail client could mark them as read or (depending on your client) you might be able to write a script to run through the emails scanning subject lines for duplicates and marking those as read while leaving one as unread.

Comment: I already thought about that solution, but in my opinion that is only a makeshift solution. Thanks anyway.